# anyone know a signed kext will expire(not working) after Apple Developer membership expires?

Tags: signed, osx-yosemite, kernel-extension

does anyone know a signed kext will expire(not working) after Apple Developer membership expires ?

please help , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/) any software signed with your developer ID will still continue to run on users' systems once your membership lapses. Note that your certificate does have its own expiry date; this is usually about 5 years from the day it was issued. I know that this date affects the ability to launch applications and installers, and I suspect it applies to kexts too, but as kext signing has only been around for a few years, no expired signatures exist yet, as far as I'm aware. You can probably find out in the xnu source.

Comment: Thanks for answer & details, will try look for more at the sun source :)